# TensorFlow: Correct way of excluding one class from loss function

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, classification

I have three classes 1 (active), 0 (inactive) and -1 (unknown). I want to build a model in TensorFlow which predicts active or inactive given the input. Is the following the correct way to calculate the loss solely over active and inactive labels and ignore the unknown ones?

```
logits = tf.reshape(logits, [-1])
labels = tf.reshape(labels, [-1])
index = tf.where(tf.not_equal(labels, tf.constant(-1, dtype=tf.float32)))
logits = tf.gather(logits, index)
labels = tf.gather(labels, index)
entropies = tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits, labels)
loss = tf.reduce_mean(entropies)
```